# "This field is required" in Django REST framework nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 serializers,

```
class AssetTypeChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AssetTypeChoice
        fields = ["id", "probe", "choice", "choice_name"]
        read_only_fields = ("probe",)
```

and a parent serializer

```
class ProbeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asset_type_choices = AssetTypeChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Probe
        fields = [
            "id",
            "city",
            "street",
            "neighborhood",
            "rooms_from",
            "rooms_to",
            "price_from",
            "price_to",
            "asset_type_choices",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        asset_type_choices = validated_data.pop("asset_type_choices")
        probe = Probe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for choice in asset_type_choices:
            AssetTypeChoice.objects.create(**choice, probe=probe)
        return probe
```

every time I'm posting to create a new probe I'm getting an error

> {
> "asset_type_choices": [
> "This field is required."
> ]
> }

when I remove AssetTypeChoiceSerializer and trying to post I'm succeeding to create a new probe.

this is my raw when I'm posting:

```
{
    "city": "test",
    "street": "",
    "neighborhood": "",
    "rooms_from": 0,
    "rooms_to": 0,
    "price_from": 0,
    "price_to": 0,
    "asset_type_choices": [
        {"id": 1, "choice": 1, "choice_name": "All"},
        {"id": 2, "choice": 1, "choice_name": "All"},
    ],
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: the problem was that in the view I user request.POST instead of request.data as it should be while using serializes of Django rest framework....

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Can you please answer your question? That will be helpful for others also. I have seen so many people have asked this question.

Comment: The essence for the community is to help others

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was when I changed my use from pure django
to django rest framework.
My view was returning request.data instead of serializer.data:

here is my code before:

```
def probe_list(request):

if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return Response({"Error": "User must be logged in"}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

if request.method == 'GET':
    qs = Probe.objects.all()
    serializer = ProbeSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = ProbeSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and here is my code after:

```
def probe_list(request):

if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return Response({"Error": "User must be logged in"}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

if request.method == 'GET':
    qs = Probe.objects.all()
    serializer = ProbeSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = ProbeSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

a newbie error but still an error.